# How does linux loader call malloc before libc.so loaded?

Tags: c, linux, loader

I find the linux loader load related so one by one. Even before libc.so loaded, loader has used malloc. But the malloc is in libc.so. Then where the malloc comes before libc.so loaded? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Ultimately all memory allocations have to be handled by the Linux kernel. That means there are system calls to get pages of virtual memory from the kernel. These system calls can be used by any application.

Comment: It make sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you should add that as an answer

Comment: Just to clearify. By "the linux loader" do you refer to the kernel (and the implementation of the exec system call) or the dynamic linker ld.so (which is provided glibc).

Comment: I think it's implied by the mention of "before libc" that this is in user-space.

Answer (score 5):

The dynamic linker has its [own implementation of malloc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/elf/dl-minimal.c.html).

Comment: I was surprised to learn this - I expected that the linker wouldn't need to free anything except a single scratch area, and so just `sbrk()` (or `mmap()`) directly.  Thanks for enlightening us!